# setDataVector - javax.swing.Table

Tags: java, swing

i had a situation where i had to use this [setDataVector](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setDataVector%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29) function. I was puzzled to see there was an extra second argument(Vector columnIdentifiers) in the function. I'm just resetting the data. Why do i need to send the column identifiers?? And it doesn't take the old column identifiers by default if i don't pass the second argument. Irritating to add initialize a vector with column identifiers only for this purpose. Any idea why it's been done like that?

Answer (score 1):

From the actual code, it looks to me like the method could have been better named. Something like setDataAndColumns() makes more sense. The internal code looks like this:

```
    this.dataVector = nonNullVector(dataVector);
    this.columnIdentifiers = nonNullVector(columnIdentifiers);
```

Passing in null for columnIdentifiers will simply remove all the columns in the table. I guess your controller class needs to keep a copy of the columnIdentifiers to pass in as required.

Comment: yep, they should have named the function more appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

The setDataVector(...) method is invoked by all the constructor methods which require you to include both parameters.